# У body в normalize стоит 0px, но user agent перебивает 8px как это возможно?

Tags: css

[На сайте](http://test.forbss.ru/index2.html) у body в normalize стоит 0px, но user agent перебивает 8px как это возможно? Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C body все нормально. Лишний отступ дает ul с классом top_navbar_menu в header'е. Поставьте ему { margin: 0 } и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Какой же я невнимательный, спасибо вам большое!